# Make Error 1 on Windows for good del command?

Tags: windows, makefile

My Makefile contains a clean rule, but for some reason it always fails, even though running the command by itself is always successful. What could possibly be causing this?

```
make clean
del /f *.o *.hex *.elf *.map
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

**Edit:** Here is the whole makefile:

```
MCU = atmega324p
AVRDUDE_DEVICE = m324p -F
PORT = \\\\.\USBSER000

CFLAGS=-g -Wall -mcall-prologues -mmcu=$(MCU) -Os
CC=avr-gcc
OBJCOPY=avr-objcopy 
OBJDUMP=avr-objdump
LDFLAGS=

TARGET=led_strip

all: $(TARGET).hex

%.hex: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@

%.elf: %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

program: $(TARGET).hex
    bootloadHID.exe -r $<

clean:
    del /f *.o *.hex *.elf *.map
```

In the meantime, I realised that WinAVR very rudely overwrote my PATH variable when I installed it. I went and added MinGW back to my PATH and removed the WinAVR utils/ folder which contained commands like sh.exe, and that seems to have fixed the issue. I would still like to understand what exactly was causing the problem, though.

Comment: Show the Makefile

Comment: Running make on Windows is slightly fraught because make invokes a shell to actually run its commands.  Depending on how your make was compiled, it may be using a UNIX shell and thus not able to run command.com commands (like `del`).  So, it depends on how this make was compiled.

Comment: Edited question to add info.

Comment: Add the value of `$(SHELL)` variable.

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to give you a definitive answer unless we can reproduce the issue, but perhaps the shell provided by WinAVR does not support the (Windows) `del` command, which is indeed odd to see in a Makefile.  Evidently, MinGW's shell does support it.